# Update Field on Child record when parent record is updated

Tags: trigger

We have Agreement object. On Parent agreement we create multiple child agreements, which Child Agreement records will appear in Relationship From Related List. This Related list is a Related Agreement Object. On Related Agreement Object we have two fields.1) Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__c(which refers Parent Record) 
2) Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r(which refers child Record).

On Parent Agreement, if we updated a Termination Date field , On child Agreement Termination Date field should be updated with which we enters on Parent Agreement.

Trigger:

trigger TerminationDateOnParent on Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c (after insert,after update) {

if(TerminationDate.isFirstTime){
    TerminationDate.isFirstTime = false;

```
Map<Id,Date> acc = new Map<Id,Date>();
for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c a:Trigger.New)    {
```

if(a.Apttus__Status_Category__c=='Terminated') {
    Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c ar=new Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c();
    acc.put(ar.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.id,a.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c);
    system.debug(acc);
}
}

List agreement = [select id,Name,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.Apttus__Status_Category__c,CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c,Apttus__Status_Category__c,Apttus__Status__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.Apttus__Status__c 
                                                 from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c 
                                                 where id in :Trigger.New 
                                                 AND Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'Terminated'
                                                 ]; 
List relagrmt=[select id,Name,Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.id,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.id,Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.Name from Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c where Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__c in: acc.keyset()]; system.debug(relagrmt); for(Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c ag:relagrmt){

```
 //Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c ar=new Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c();
   //ar.Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.id=ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.id;
ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c=acc.get(ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.id);
    update ag;
    system.debug(ag);
    system.debug(ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_To__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c);
                system.debug(ag.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c);

      }
```

}
}

@Ayub , This is my modified trigger, now am getting date value @line no 11, debug logs giving all the records and my condition is also satified and giving Termination date as on Parent record. But I child record is not updating eventhough condition satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the related child object record having no value in any field

```
Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c ar=new Apttus__APTS_Related_Agreement__c();
```

And then just after that, you are trying to access parent field's date even though this object is still blank:

```
 ar.Apttus__APTS_Contract_From__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c
```